# React Native WebView

Tags: typescript, webview, react-native

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

<Button
  title="Press me"
  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(google.com)}
/>
```

Есть кнопка которая переходит по ссылке, но переходит она через браузер.
Как можно сделать что-бы кнопка работала через WebView ?

Comment: Рендерите WebView по условию
По нажатию на кнопку это условие должно удовлетвориться.
В интернете же есть куча примеров, не пробовали загуглить?

Comment: я только начал изучать ReactNative, гуглил не смог найти ответ на вопрос, в туториалах до конца не смог разобратся...

Comment: лови пример как можно сделать

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
type State = {
  showWV: boolean,
  url: string,
};

class TestComp extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showWV: false, url: ''}
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.showWV && <WebView source={{ uri: this.state.url }}/>}
        <Button
          title="Press me"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ showWV: true; url: 'https://google.com'})}
        />
      </View>);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Visual studio ругается:
- Параметр "props" неявно имеет тип "any".
- Свойство "showWV" не существует в типе "Readonly<{}>".
- Свойство "url" не существует в типе "Readonly<{}>".

Comment: ну, это проблема TypeScript, а не конкретно этого примера, тебе нужно добавить типы к объекту this.state и props. Если нет понимания TypeScript, может сначала с ним разобраться/изучить или попробуй отключить линтинг и проверку типов.

Comment: @RomaCrypton попробуй так

Comment: теперь проблема с WebView:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<WebViewProps>): WebView', gave the following error.
    Тип "{ uri: string | undefined; }" не может быть назначен для типа "WebViewSourceUri | WebViewSourceHtml | undefined".
     Типы свойства "uri" несовместимы.

Comment: @RomaCrypton а сейчас?)

Comment: проблема осталась только в одной строчке -
//  constructor(props) { //

вот она:
//  параметр 'props' неявно имеет 'any' //